# Google Stackdriver Logging add comments to advanced filter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, comments, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I wanted to document some of the more complicated Stackdriver logging filters I'm using. I'd prefer to put the comments near the relevant sections of the filter instead of a separate file, but I can't find any method for adding comments in the docs. Is there a way?

If there isn't an official way, does anyone have a hack to add no-effect statements with arbitrary text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently commenting within Stackdriver's advanced logging feature is not available.

I did create feature request found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120948950) that you can follow to stay up-to-date on the feature.

Comment: The issue is now marked as resolved (a mere 5 years later...), but I can't for the life of me figure out how the comments are supposed to work. Is it a `#` or `//` or `/**/` 

Answer (score 0):

Well, as workaround I added a block in a new line (which means AND logic):

```
(true OR "# Your Comment Here")

<your query here>
```